# Plotting one daily time serie per year in R (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Similar to this question: [Split up time series per year for plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60140744/split-up-time-series-per-year-for-plotting) which has done in Python, I want to display the daily time series as multiple lines by year. How can I achieve this in R?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Dummy data
df <- data.frame(
  day = as.Date("2017-06-14") - 0:364,
  value = runif(365) + seq(-140, 224)^2 / 10000
)

# Most basic bubble plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=day, y=value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("")
p
```

Out:

[image]

One solution is using `ggplot2`, but `date_labels` are displayed incorrectly:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
p <- df %>% 
  # mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  mutate(date=as.Date(date)) %>% 
  mutate(
    year = factor(year(date)),     # use year to define separate curves
    date = update(date, year = 1)  # use a constant year for the x-axis
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, value, color = year)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b")

# Raw daily data
p + geom_line()
```

Out:

[image]

Alternative solution is to use `gg_season` from `feasts` package:

```
library(feasts)
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)
tsibbledata::aus_retail %>%
  filter(
    State == "Victoria",
    Industry == "Cafes, restaurants and catering services"
  ) %>%
  gg_season(Turnover)
```

Out:

[image]

**References:**

[Split up time series per year for plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60140744/split-up-time-series-per-year-for-plotting)

[R - How to create a seasonal plot - Different lines for years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722758/r-how-to-create-a-seasonal-plot-different-lines-for-years)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your x axis to represent the months from January to February, then perhaps getting the `yday` of the date and adding it to the first of January on a random year would be simplest:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  day = as.Date("2017-06-14") - 0:364,
  value = runif(365) + seq(-140, 224)^2 / 10000
)

df %>% 
  mutate(year = factor(year(day)), date = yday(day) + as.Date('2017-01-01')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, value, color = year)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), by = 'month', length = 12),
               date_labels = '%b')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, is it possible to avoid pass `2017-01-01` as a parameter, because I hope to convert it to a general function which is suitable to any daily, weekly even monthly time serie data.

Comment: @ahbon the point is, the year doesn't matter. This could be the first of January 2000 or 1066. It's simply specifiying that we want a number of days on from the first of January. The year never appears in the plot, so it is irrelevant, and will work on any set of dates. The year can be safely hard-coded in the body of the function without it being specificied as a parameter.

Comment: I got it, but find a new issue. If we have `NA`s in `value` column, it will not work, how could we deal with this?

Comment: @ahbon it still works for me on your example data if I put several NA values in the value column (or indeed in the day column).  I get the same axes, but gaps in the lines where the NA values are (as expected). Are you able to show a reproducible example of it not working?

Comment: Sorry, after I reviewed my code, the error is not come from `NA`s. `ggplot(aes(date, 'value', color = year))` will generate this error, instead, I should use `ggplot(aes(date, value, color = year))` or ggplot(aes(date, `value`, color = year)).

Answer (score 3):

I tend to think simple is better:

```r
transform(df, year = format(day, "%Y")) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=day, y=value, group=year, color=year)) +
  geom_line() +
  xlab(NULL)
```

[image: ggplot line by year]

optionally removing the `year` legend with `+ guides(colour = "none")`.

Comment: I agree with regards to this data set, but I get the impression that the OP was looking for something that could plot January to December, with potentially overlapping series showing multiple years on a single plot. From a data viz viewpoint, I would normally stick with your approach unless I really wanted to highlight a specific seasonal change in one particular year.

Comment: That's a good thought, I hadn't interpreted the question that way (I think the question is a bit vague). Thanks @AllanCameron

Comment: ... and I lost an upvote, sigh.

Comment: You got mine, but not everyone sees the bigger picture it seems!